# Python Class / always return 0

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, division, operands

I have created a class called bootcamp that allows users to add completed tasks, view all tasks they are supposed to do and also check on their incompleted tasks. The question is i have created an algorithm to check progress in percentage where i divide the length of the completed list over the length of total tasks lists. I initially thought it does not record the changes since it always returns zero but after testing with other operands such as + and * it works well. Why does division always return 0? Sharing the code would help understand my problem:

```
class Bootcamp(object):
    tasks = {1: "TDD", 2: "OOP", 3: "Programming Logic", 4: "Version 
          Control", 5: "Agile Methodology",
                       6: "Growth Mindset", 7: "Asking Questions", 8: 
                  "Motivation and Commitment", 9: "Speaking"}
    def __init__(self, name, tasks=tasks):
        self.name = name
        self.tasks = tasks
        self.completed = []
        self.incompleted = tasks.values()

    def add_completed_items(self, i):
        if i in self.tasks.keys():
            self.completed.append(self.tasks[i])
            self.incompleted.remove(self.tasks[i])
            return "tasks added to complete"
        else:
            return "not in the tasks"


nick = Bootcamp("nick")
total_work = int(len(nick.tasks))
print nick.add_completed_items(1)
print nick.add_completed_items(2)
print nick.add_completed_items(3)
comleted_work = int(len(nick.completed))
progress = (comleted_work  / total_work) * 100
print nick.incompleted` 
print progress`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's simple. You are trying to divide an int by another int, that's the trouble. Python performs integer division in that case, and you are trying to divide a lesser int by a larger one, of course you should get 0 almost always (except when the ints are equal)

Replace `int`s with `float`s, like this

```
total_work = float(len(nick.tasks))
...
comleted_work = float(len(nick.completed))
```

and the problem should be solved

Comment: It worked.....it gave me alot of headache since i thought me method was not working. Now i can implement it inside the class

Comment: Somewhat better solution: Move to Py3 style division by adding `from __future__ import division` to the top of your file. Then `/` will produce floating point results. If you want floor division, you use `//` to opt-in explicitly.